# Error in finding the minimum of a dataset, subsetted from a large data frame

Tags: r, split, subset

**Problem Objective:** Finding the Best Hospital in a State

**Data File if Needed:** [outcome-of-care-measures.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XBUP4dwXy6KupirP0yA1xB1VAhsdaxza/view?usp=sharing)

**Explanation** 
I am working with hospital data for different states in the USA. The csv file contains information about 30-day mortality and readmission rates for heart attacks, heart failure, and pneumonia for over 4,000 hospitals.

I want to write a function called 'best' that take two arguments: the 2-character abbreviated name of a state (e.g: 'NY' for New York) and an outcome name. The function reads the 'outcome-of-care-measures.csv' file and returns a character vector with the name of the hospital that has the best (i.e. lowest) 30-day mortality for the specified outcome in that state. The hospital name is the name provided in the Hospital.Name variable in the csv file. The outcomes can be one of “heart attack”, “heart failure”, or “pneumonia”. Hospitals that do not have data on a particular outcome should be excluded from the set of hospitals when deciding the rankings

The function should check the validity of its arguments. If an invalid state value is passed to best, the function should throw an error via the stop function with the exact message “invalid state”. If an invalid outcome value is passed to best, the function should throw an error via the stop function with the exact message “invalid outcome”.

**Code I Wrote:**

```
best <- function(state,outcome) {
  df <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv")
  df1 <- df[ ,c(2,7,11,17,23)] # column numbers correspond to the columns of interest from the entire csv file
  table <- split(df1,df1$State)
  if (outcome == "heart attack") {
    n = 3
  } else if (outcome == "heart failure") {
    n = 4
  } else if (outcome == "pneumonia") {
    n = 5
  } else {
    stop("Invalid Outcome")
  }

  min.val <- min(table$state[,n],na.rm = TRUE)
  row.no <- which(table$state[,n] == min.val)
  print(table$state[1,row.no])
}
```

**Error**

```
best("TX", "heart failure")
NULL
Warning message:
In min(table$state[, n], na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Comment: `split` returns a list of objects. You never actually filter data frame by input *state* value. Try `sub_df <- df1[df1$State==state,]` or `sub_df <- subset(df, State==state)`. Also try not naming object as actual R functions such as *table*.

Comment: a few things worth addressing: (1) `table` will be a `list` of different state data, so `table$state` would not give data on TX, though `table$TX` or `table[["TX"]]` would; try `table[[state]]` or @Parfait's approach; (2) the result for TX example is a factor, if you want minimum it should be numeric (consider `as.numeric`); (3) for `print` did you want [row.no, 1] (were these reversed)?